# DisclosureGroup Pushes Entire HStack View Down When Expanded

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, view

I have a DisclosureGroup that sits within an HStack with other views. When the disclosreGroup is expanded it adjusts the height of the HStack to fit the expanded DisclosureGroup causing the other views in my HStack to be pushed down since their alignment is adjusting to the new expanded height.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack () {
            DisclosureGroup("    Tail Number / MDS") {
                Text("This is just fake text")
                Text("This is just fake text")
                Text("This is just fake text")
                Text("This is just fake text")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("My Issues")
                Toggle("", isOn: $showMyIssues).labelsHidden()
            }
                            
            Text("Add Report")
        }
        
        //More Views in the VStack
    }
}
```

First picture shows the disclouregroup not exapnded. second picture shows it expanded and it pushing the entire HStack view down.

[image: Not Expanded]

[image: Expanded]

Is there a way to set it so the DisclosureGroup does not adjust the height of the parent view (the HStack). Rather, it would expand and overlay on top of everything below it?

Comment: That is normal behavior.

Comment: So what is the question here? What is your desired output?

Comment: @burnsi Sorry, the question part of the post I forgot to add. *See the last paragraph

Comment: No you can't change that behavior

Comment: I wonder about trying to use some padding. I've adjusted my disclosures with .padding() modifiers. It worked for me to push Text() up and down.